# Querying Heart Rate value from HealthKit crashes app

Tags: ios, swift, healthkit

I'm trying to get my heart rate shown as a label whenever i press a button. I want to be able to choose a specific day also when the heart rate is printed I want to be able to email this specific rate by email. But my main question is i'm getting constantly "Thread 1: signal SIGABRT" whenever I click my button. Everything seem to be linked as supposed.

```
import UIKit
import HealthKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
let healthStore = HKHealthStore()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

@IBAction func authoriseHealthKitAccess(_ sender: Any) {
    let healthKitTypes: Set = [

        HKObjectType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.heartRate)!
    ]
    healthStore.requestAuthorization(toShare: healthKitTypes, read: healthKitTypes) { (_, _) in
        print("Authorising")
    }
    healthStore.requestAuthorization(toShare: healthKitTypes, read: healthKitTypes) { (bool, error) in
        if let e = error {
            print("oops something went wrong during authorisation \(e.localizedDescription)")
        } else {
            print("User has completed the authorization process")
        }
    }
}

func getTodaysHeartRate(completion: @escaping (Double) -> Void) {

    let heartRateType = HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .heartRate)!

    let now = Date()
    let startOfDay = Calendar.current.startOfDay(for: now)
    let predicate = HKQuery.predicateForSamples(withStart: startOfDay, end: now, options: .strictStartDate)

    let query = HKStatisticsQuery(quantityType: heartRateType, quantitySamplePredicate: predicate, options: .cumulativeSum) { (_, result, error) in
        var resultCount = 0
        guard let result = result else {
            print("Failed to fetch heart rate")
            completion(Double(resultCount))
            return
        }
        if let sum = result.sumQuantity() {
            resultCount = Int(sum.doubleValue(for: HKUnit.count()))
        }

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            completion(Double(resultCount))
        }
    }
    healthStore.execute(query)
}

@IBOutlet weak var heartRate: UILabel!
@IBAction func getHeartRate(_ sender: Any) {
    getTodaysHeartRate { (result) in
        print("\(result)")
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.heartRate.text = "\(result)"
        }
}
}

}
```

> Crash Console:
>   2019-02-22 14:29:28.314380-0400 
>   HeartRateSample[16416:2767191] *** Terminating app due 
>   to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', 
>   reason: 'Statistics option 
>   HKStatisticsOptionCumulativeSum is not compatible with discrete data type HKQuantityTypeIdentifierHeartRate'
>   *** First throw call stack: (0x213d51ea4 0x212f21a50 0x213c58484 0x2265cf760 0x226575d60 0x22657e298 0x1035e4dc8 0x1035f382c
>   0x22657dcb0 0x226534bd4 0x102749ebc 0x10274a8dc 0x10274ae3c
>   0x24103e314 0x240acbd54 0x240acc074 0x240acb074 0x241077a6c
>   0x241078cd0 0x241057fcc 0x241126e38 0x241129830 0x241122320
>   0x213ce20e0 0x213ce2060 0x213ce1944 0x213cdc810 0x213cdc0e0
>   0x215f55584 0x24103cc00 0x10274d138 0x21379abb4) libc++abi.dylib:
>   terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException (lldb)

Comment: That's because `sumQuantity` is used, which is for cumulative data like steps. As Bhaumik answered, use `mostRecentQuantity`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are on the right track. Error you are getting is straightforward. Heart rate is a discrete option and is not compatible with statistic option Cumulative Sum.

**From documentation:**

> You cannot combine a discrete option with a cumulative option.

[Click here to learn more about HKStatisticsOptions](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/hkstatisticsoptions)

**Solution:**

You need to use .discreteMostRecent instead of <strike>.cumulativeSum</strike>

Updated code to accommodate necessary changes:

```
@available(iOS 12.0, *)
    func getTodaysHeartRate(completion: @escaping (Double) -> Void) {
        let heartRateType = HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .heartRate)!
        let now = Date()
        let startOfDay = Calendar.current.startOfDay(for: now)
        let predicate = HKQuery.predicateForSamples(withStart: startOfDay, end: now, options: .strictStartDate)

    // replaced options parameter .cumulativeSum with .discreteMostRecent
    let query = HKStatisticsQuery(quantityType: heartRateType, quantitySamplePredicate: predicate, options: .discreteMostRecent) { (_, result, error) in
        var resultCount = 0
        guard let result = result else {
            print("Failed to fetch heart rate")
            completion(Double(resultCount))
            return
        }

        // More changes here in order to get bpm value
        guard let beatsPerMinute: Double = result.mostRecentQuantity()?.doubleValue(for: HKUnit.count().unitDivided(by: HKUnit.minute())) else { return }
        resultCount = Int(beatsPerMinute)

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            completion(Double(resultCount))
        }
    }
    healthStore.execute(query)
}
```

**Note:** .discreteMostRecent option is only available on iOS 12 or newer.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks Bhaumik. Working as intended!

Comment: I'm glad that it helped!